# Odoo showing KeyError: 'last_path_node' after migrate from v12 to v13 with Openupgrade

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I migrate my odoo instance from v12 to v13 using Openupgrade without errors. I also made change in my code and update my custom modules using

```
 python3 odoo-bin --addons-path="./addons, ./extra_addons, ./OCA/contract" -p 8069 -d database_name -u module_name
```

also without error. My odoo instance is apparently loading without error, I can even see the odoo main interface but when and click an element from the main menu (lets say "contacts") it shows "Internal Server Error" and when I check the logs I can see the following errors "    path = options['last_path_node']
KeyError: 'last_path_node'"

Where is the full log of the error

```
**Contexto del error:
Vista `App Drawer - Web Client`
[view_id: 941, xml_id: web_responsive.webclient_bootstrap, model: n/a, parent_id: 178] 
2022-09-08 13:33:39,610 19400 INFO wimax13 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2022 13:33:39] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 - 386 0.534 1.152
2022-09-08 13:33:39,973 19400 ERROR wimax13 werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/service/server.py", line 439, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 1287, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 1257, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 1457, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 172, in _dispatch
    response = super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/auth_signup/models/ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
    return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 21, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/utm/models/ir_http.py", line 29, in _dispatch
    response = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 519, in _dispatch
    result = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 238, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/utm/models/ir_http.py", line 34, in _handle_exception
    response = super(IrHttp, cls)._handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 610, in _handle_exception
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 206, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 750, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 234, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 809, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 342, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 1236, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/http.py", line 1229, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"].render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1191, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 336, in render
    return super(View, self).render(values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1199, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 58, in render
    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 260, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "<decorator-gen-54>", line 2, in compile
    
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 113, in compile
    return super(IrQWeb, self).compile(id_or_xml_id, options=options)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 277, in compile
    element, document = self.get_template(template, options)
  File "/home/ernesto/Programming/odoo/wimax13/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 364, in get_template
    path = options['last_path_node']
KeyError: 'last_path_node' - - -**
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the spaces in your addons-path setting? That's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the third line of your Traceback, your error seems to be related with this view:

```
view_id: 941, xml_id: web_responsive.webclient_bootstrap
```

You can access this view using  its id: 941 in this kind of url:
https://your-oerp.odoo.com/web?#id=941&action=28&model=ir.ui.view&view_type=form
to provide me its content... to investigate the error

Is this view (with relativ high id: 941) "not native" / part of your custom module ?

On the other hand, this view name (id:941): "web_responsive.webclient_bootstrap" doesn t exist in Odoo 13 and seems to have been replaced:
[image]

In Odoo 13, the existing bootstrap-related views are:

- web._assets_bootstrap
- web.webclient_bootstrap
- web_enterprise.webclient_bootstrap
- web_studio.webclient_bootstrap